# A differentiable function $f$ with maximum at $x=c\Rightarrow f''(c)<0$ true OR false

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

State true or false
A differentiable function $f$ with maximum at $x=c\Rightarrow f''(c)<0$

---

I think this is a true statement but my book says this is a false statement.I do not understand why this is a false.My reasoning is when a function is maximum at a point $x=c$,then that function is concave down at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider

$$f(x)=-x^4$$

at $x=0$. The graph is concave down but the second derivative is zero at the maximum.

Remember, the second derivative test says that (assuming $f(c)=0$) if $f''(c)<0$ then $f$ has a maximum at $c$: it does not say the converse.

Answer (score 1):

Without further conditions on $f$, your statement may even be meaningless. Consider an everywhere-differentiable function on $[a, b]$ which is nowhere second-differentiable. It is bounded and attains its bounds (because it is continuous), so it has a maximum; but the second derivative does not exist at that maximum.